# locationManager:didEnterRegion: only getting called when moving from certain locations

Tags: iphone, ios, core-location

I'm monitoring a region using CLLocationManager's `startMonitoringForRegion:desiredAccuracy:`. I know for sure that the region gets properly added to the location manager's monitoredRegions.

I set this up while my simulator location is set far away from it (2.3 km to be precise). Then I hit the home button, and change the simulator's location to the very location I set a geofence for. `locationManager:didEnterRegion:` doesn't get called. Same results if I try moving to this location but from a another location, this one 4.3 km away.

There seems to be some threshold I can't pick up, as locationManager:didEnterRegion: gets called when moving from other locations at 7 km and up. **But my CLRegion's radius is 100 m.** What could possibly be the issue here?

Comment: I have been experiencing the same problem in the 5.1 SDK's iOS Simulator. The timing coincided with installing iOS 6 beta 3, but I'm not at all sure this is the cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is truly just a wild guess, but I wonder if this is a result of the location manager attempting to mitigate false positives with a location that is seemingly jumping around. I imagine that changing the location in the simulator while the app is resigned could appear to the location manager as a location update that doesn't conform to the desired accuracy, thus disregarding it when considering whether you've actually entered a new region.

Have you tried simulating a city bike ride or freeway drive to see if it makes a difference? I would just try to test on a device as soon as possible.

Comment: Indeed, it seems that region monitoring isn't so reliable on the iOS Simulator if what you want to do is fine tuning.

Comment: I am having this problem even with small location changes. You could try my script for simulating incremental movement to see whether this solves it for you: https://github.com/yangmeyer/YMDevScripts